# How to copy a column but stop once it hits a 0 or a blank

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a macro to copy an entire column of data but stop once it hits a 0 or blank as I only want the cells in the column that actually have data in them.

**Edit:**

```
Worksheets("C_Plan").Select
Range("O13").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy Worksheets("Summary").Select
Range("A4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

I forgot to mention i am pasting from 3 different worksheets and after i select the data in one worksheet, I need the second paste to start where the first paste left off. I have been using

```
Selection.End(xlDown).Select 
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

Comment: show, please, what have you tried so far

Comment: very much brute force type code:
Worksheets("C_Plan").Select
    Range("O13").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Worksheets("Summary").Select
    Range("A4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,      SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False


i forgot to mention i am pasting from 3 different worksheets and after i select the data in one worksheet, I need the second paste to start where the first paste left off. I have been using
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and tell me if this works for you

```
Sub Test()
Dim R As Integer
Dim P As Integer
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Select
R = Range("O65536").End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range(Cells(1, 15), Cells(R, 15)).Select
Selection.Copy

ws2.Select
P = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
ws2.Cells(P, 1).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

This will select all the Cells in column O with a value and copy it and then paste it to the worksheet "summary" starting in the last cell in Column A with data.

Comment: i am going to try these two once i get a minute to play around, they both look like code i can use to force excel to only look at columns with data :)

Comment: I am getting an error 424 "object required"

cPlan.Range(Cells(1, 15), Cells(R, 15)).Select.Copy

i changed the names obviously but defined them as the same thing.

Comment: edited the code try now also added the .offset(1,0).select so it doesnt overwrite the last value.  Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the top-most cell of your column stored as `startCell as Range` I would do something like this:

```
dim endCell as Range
dim colRange as Range

set endCell = startCell ' Here's where you'll need startCell already!
While endCell <> "" And endCell <> "0"
  set endCell = endCell.Offset(1) ' Move down the column
Loop

set colRange = Range(startCell, endCell)
' Now you can do with "colRange" as you please. Copy, paste etc.
```